# $7^{10}$ by $51$ what rest?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences

How to find the remains of Division $7^{10}$ by $51$ using arithmetic debris?

$$$$
$$7\equiv51\;\text{mod}11$$

Comment: The remains rest peacefully under arithmetic debris.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note this:

\begin{align}
7^2 &\equiv - 2 &\pmod{51} \\
7^{10} &\equiv - 32 &\pmod{51} \\
7^{10} &\equiv 19 &\pmod{51} \\
\end{align}

So this means that the remainder will be 19.

Comment: The first line to the second, you multiply the first times the first times the first, five times?

Comment: You can do that, but exponation is better.

$$(7^2)^5 = 7^{10}$$
$$ -2^5 = -32$$

Comment: I understand.
But the passage from the second to the third line? I do not understand.

Comment: 32+19=51.  When working in modulo, one can add the number and still be congruent.  In mod 2, $1=-1$ as they differ by 2.

Comment: @JBKing Ah yes ..
For example if the question were "finding the remains of division $2^{100}$ by $11$, I would $$2^4\equiv5\;\text{mod}\;11$$$$2^{100}\equiv 5^{25}\; \text{mod}\;11$$And then what?

Comment: @marcelolpjunior, if you know Fermat's Little Theorem then you could use that $2^{10}$ will be congruent to $1$ mod $11$ and thus, $2^{100}$ will just be 1.  93*11=1023 which is 1 less than $2^{10}=1024$

Comment: @JBKing $$2^{10}\equiv 1\;\text{mod}\;11\Longrightarrow(2^{10})^{10}\equiv1^{10}\;\text{mod}\;11 \Longrightarrow 2^{100}\equiv1\;\text{mod}\;11\;\;?$$$$$$Soon, the rest will be $1$, correct?

Comment: That's correct, the result will be 1.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/10115/discussion-between-marcelolpjunior-and-jb-king)

Comment: And if you want to know something more you can learn a litle bit here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic

Answer (score 1):

$7^3=343=17\cdot20+3$, so $7^3\equiv3\pmod{17}$, and $7^{10}\equiv3^3\cdot7\equiv27\cdot7\equiv10\cdot7\equiv2\pmod{17}$, since $4\cdot17=68$. Of course $7^{10}\equiv1^{10}\equiv1\pmod3$. Thus, we want an integer $n\in\{0,1,\dots,50\}$ such that $n\equiv2\pmod{17}$ and $n\equiv1\pmod3$; $2+17=19$ clearly does the trick.